# Inspect config XML tree magento generates

Tags: magento

As the title implies, I want to inspect the complete config XML tree generated by Magento.

I have looked at the config object and cannot see a way to do this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the config xml in its entirety (as xml which is what I assume you are referring to)...

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->getXmlString();
```

It will be much easier to inspect if you save it to a file.  The following will save to a file at var/tmp/configxml.xml...

```
file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('tmp').DS.'configxml.xml', Mage::app()->getConfig()->getXmlString());
```

Obviously, Magento has to have been bootstrapped first.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this would come in handy so I built a tiny Magento module that will show the config if you add ?showConfig=1 to the URL.  Props to Drew Hunter for the initial code.

https://github.com/siliconrockstar/showconfig